# inputrc command not found

Tags: linux, bash, key-bindings

I'm trying to modify `.inputrc` to change key-bindings for bash, so I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> with the arrow keys, but when I source the changes I get "command not found".

I have the following options set:

```
set enable-keypad on

# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow
"\e[D": beginning-of-line
"\e[C": end-of-line
```

I have used the read utility to determine the keybindings. 
I have also tried the [bind command](https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/bind/). Am I setting this in correct place?

Comment: `.inputrc` is not a shell script and can't be sourced. See [How do I reload .inputrc?](https://superuser.com/questions/241187/how-do-i-reload-inputrc)

Comment: So i unbinded the command that uses `"\e[C"` key and then ran `bind -f ~/.inputrc` as recommended in the linked post, but none of the keybinds in my .inputrc file got set. Anything else I'm forgetting or not setting up right?